# wordpress admin text turn to icons

Tags: php, wordpress, fonts, themes

Has any body had this sort of problem before. The text mainly in input field descriptions turns to weird icons see image. I have deactivated all plugins and changed themes several times but same happens. However it sometimes starts working and then will just suddenly to the same thing.

[image: wordpress desc fields showing weird icon font]

Comment: does it happen in all browsers?

Comment: @TomeӾsanS just checked and seems to be chrome only, it seems to be working okay although when changing font-size in browser using the inspect element at certain sizes it will change to the weird icons (this in on a wordpress front end page).